# Hibernate one to one mapping creates a foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Background: I load up a mysql instance to run DB tests and I create my schema using Hibernate (spring-data-jpa) and run some tests against the DB. All my Entities are created via annotation and loaded in a spring context.

Tables: I have 2 tables:

```
MainTable:
   - id (PK)
   - customerId
   ...

ThirdParty:
   - id (PK)
   - customerId (FK: MainTable.customerId)
   - serviceId
```

This is a one-to-one mapping as I don't want to add serviceId to my MainTable.

My entities are setup as follows:

```
@Table
@Entity
public class MainTable {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private String customerId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private ThirdParty thirdParty;
}

@Table
@Entity
public class ThirdParty {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private String customerId;

    @Column(name = "SERVICE_ID")
    private String serviceId;
}
```

I want MainTable.thirdParty to be nullable.
Whenever Hibernate creates the schema, it creates a FK relationship from MainTable.CUSTOMER_ID on ThirdParty.CUSTOMER_ID meaning I get a ref integrity problem when trying to persist MainTable with null thirdParty.

I just really want to be able to store an instance of MainTable which may be with or without ThirdParty data.

I don't want Hibernate to create the MainTable with a FK relation on ThirdParty.customerId

Comment: Removing the `@OneToOne` relation from `MainTable` should do the trick.

Comment: @Turing85 that sort of worked, but it removed the FK from ThirdParty.customerId to MainTable.customerId as well. I also get errors persisting an instance of MainTable when I set an instance of thirdParty as well. (Using spring-data-jpa) and only running `repo.save(mainTableInstance);`